# Flowplayer won't load specific flv video

Tags: flash, flowplayer

I've used flowplayer successfully a few times on my site, and in fact this page works if I swap in a different flv file in the same folder.

It seems like there's a problem with the flv perhaps, though both open fine in vlc player. Can anyone see what's wrong?

[The page is here](http://djembefola.com/test.html) (videos take a little while to load), but as you can see 1 & 3 work fine, the 2nd one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with how the video was encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your file name has a space between, would replace the space with %20 solve your problem?

EDIT: I did some testing with your provided flv on my environment, and it looks like this is not the problem of the space, but rather the version of the flowplayer you are using. You are currently using version 3.1.5 of the flowplayer, and after I changed that to the one we are currently using, the video can playback.

However, there is still a problem there that while we play the video, there is only sound but no images. Since you have mentioned that if you swap the flv with another one, it will work, I suspect this could be an issue of both flv itself and the version of flowplayer you are using.

Try to download a new version of flowplayer and plug into your code see if it works, otherwise try to encode your movie again.

Hopefully this can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have upgraded to the latest version and removed all the mess on the page and I still have the same behaviour. Any ideas? Can you get the second video to play on your install of flowplayer?